# How to create advanced soaprequest in php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Hi i don't have a lot of experience with programming a web service client. In the past (before web services where common) i worked with php so i am going back to my roots.

With soapui i created the following (working) request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eng="urn:hpexstream-services/Engine">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<eng:Compose>
<EWSComposeRequest>
<driver>
<driver>base64encodedstring</driver>
<fileName>INPUT</fileName>
</driver>
<engineOptions>
<name>KEY</name>    <value>string</value>
</engineOptions>
<fileReturnRegEx>^.*.(pdf|dlf)$</fileReturnRegEx>
<includeHeader>True</includeHeader>
<includeMessageFile>True</includeMessageFile>
<pubFile>InteractiveDocument.pub</pubFile>
</EWSComposeRequest>
</eng:Compose>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In the first phase of my project i want to make a soapclient in php that creates the soaprequest as shown above. If this works i want to expand this project with a form providing the variables.

I have tried several php scripts, done a lot of tuturials but all of them all simple in comparison to my situation. So i am stuck...

With this script i do reach my soapserver, but it gives back an undefined error:

> 

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/EngineService/EngineService?wsdl");
$answer = $client->Compose("EWSComposeRequest", array('driver' =>     "base64encodedstring",'fileName' => "INPUT",'fileReturnRegEx' => "^.*.(pdf|dlf)$",'includeHeader' => "True","includeMessageFile" => "True","pubFile" => "InteractiveDocument.pub" ))
```

?>

I really hope that someone can help me with this. 
Thanks in advance!

With kind regards,
Mijno

Answer (score 1):

After a day of hard work, searching the internet and a lot of trial and error, i managed to get it working.

Here is the code that did the trick:

```
    <?php

// maken the functions that we are going to use
function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
            echo "\n\n";
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            echo "\n\n";
            return $d;
        }
    }




// Fill in the parameters, this will be replaced with results from a form & an initialisation file
$soap_EndPoint          = "http://somehost:8080/EngineService/EngineService";
$soap_Wsdl              = "${soap_EndPoint}?wsdl";
$p_strDriver            = "base64encodedstring";
$p_strFileName          = "INPUT";
$p_strFileReturnRegEx   = "^.*.(pdf|dlf)$";
$p_strIncludeHeader = "True";
$p_strIncludeMessage    = "True";
$p_strPubFile           = "InteractiveDocument.pub";
$p_strEngineKey     = "removedstring";


// preparing soap client connection 

$soap_opts = array (
        'location'   =>  $soap_EndPoint ,
        'style'      =>  SOAP_DOCUMENT,
        'use'        =>  SOAP_LITERAL,
        'cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' =>  TRUE,
        'trace'      =>  TRUE,
        'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP);


$soapclient_result = new SoapClient($soap_Wsdl, $soap_opts);
$soap_header = new SoapHeader("urn:hpexstream-services/Engine",'','',FALSE);
$soap_param = array("Compose"=> array("EWSComposeRequest" => array( "driver" => array( "driver" => $p_strDriver, "fileName" => $p_strFileName), "engineOptions" => array( "name" => "KEY", "value" => $p_strEngineKey), "fileReturnRegEx" => $p_strFileReturnRegEx, "includeHeader" => $p_strIncludeHeader, "includeMessageFile" => $p_strIncludeMessage, "pubFile" => $p_strPubFile)));



try {
    $result = $soapclient_result->__soapCall("Compose", $soap_param, NULL, $soap_header, $soap_outputHeaders);

    /* turn on for debuggin
    echo $soapclient_result->__getLastRequest();
    echo "\n\n";
    echo $soapclient_result->__getLastResponse(); 
    echo "\n\n";
    echo $soapclient_result->__getLastResponseHeaders(); 
    echo $soapclient_result->__getTypes(); 
    echo "\n\n";
        */

// the result is set in objects instead of an array     
$array = objectToArray($result);


//  creating some variables for the files i receive from the soap server
$timeStamp  = Time();
$msgFile        .= 'hpoutput/'. $timeStamp . '_messageFile.txt';
$dlfFile        .= 'hpoutput/'. $timeStamp . '_'. $array["return"]["files"]["fileName"];

// saving the messagefile to the server
$var_str    = var_export($array["return"]["engineMessage"], true);
file_put_contents($msgFile, $var_str);

// saving the actual output file to the server 
$var_str    = serialize($array["return"]["files"]["fileOutput"]);
file_put_contents($dlfFile, $var_str);


} catch (SoapFault $fault) {

    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);

}


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

How to create advanced soap request in java

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eng="urn:hpexstream-services/Engine">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<eng:Compose>
<EWSComposeRequest>
<driver>
<driver>PGN1c3RvbWVyPg0KICAgPGZpcnN0TmFtZT5NZXJpZW08L2ZpcnN0TmFtZT4NCiAgICAgIDxsYXN0TmFtZT5CZWxtb2todGFyPC9sYXN0TmFtZT4NCiAgIA0KPC9jdXN0b21lcj4NCjxjdXN0b21lcj4NCiAgIDxmaXJzdE5hbWU+QWhtZWQ8L2ZpcnN0TmFtZT4NCiAgICAgIDxsYXN0TmFtZT5CZW91bWFpejwvbGFzdE5hbWU+DQogICANCjwvY3VzdG9tZXI+DQo8Y3VzdG9tZXI+DQogICA8Zmlyc3ROYW1lPkhhbXphPC9maXJzdE5hbWU+DQogICAgICA8bGFzdE5hbWU+QmVua2hhbGVkPC9sYXN0TmFtZT4NCiAgIA0KPC9jdXN0b21lcj4=</driver>
<fileName>INPUT</fileName>
</driver>
<driverEncoding>UTF-8</driverEncoding>
<engineOptions>
<name>RUNMODE</name>
<value>PRODUCTION</value>
</engineOptions>
<fileReturnRegEx>?</fileReturnRegEx>
<includeHeader>?</includeHeader>
<includeMessageFile>?</includeMessageFile>
<outputFile>
<directory>out</directory>
<fileName>sortie</fileName>
</outputFile>
<pubFile>PackageTest.pub</pubFile>
</EWSComposeRequest>
</eng:Compose>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```